# "Open in Safari" for sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

At the bottom of questions and answers is a link (or a menu containing a link) to open the relevant post in Safari from the iOS app. Can a similar link be implemented on the "more" tab for the site, in the "actions" section?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the app though? The way I see it from the SE teams view point is you may want the full web experience for a question or answer but while you're using the app **you want a native experience**. That's just me though. I can't see why not, but that's seems to be a valid rationale for why it's not there currently.

Comment: @DanielJames Yeah, sure, but there's still plenty of features in the browser - even the mobile one - that the app doesn't have, that someone might want to use. (Besides, according to your logic, why is there such a link on the posts?)

Comment: one reason seems to be that you can't undelete a question / answer in the app so there is a web link so you can. Although I'm not sure of the true reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be added in 1.6.5.3.

It'll be on the More tab under "Open Chat".